No new NServiceBus Saga instance is created when another IAmStarted message is run
I couldn't find any similar topic so I am creating new one. I have strange problem which is not how Sagas usually behave.
When I fire two IAmStartedBy messages, then first one creates new Saga instance, but second one always find the first instance... It should create new, because passed correlation id is different, but it uses the first one instead... Even if first one is Marked as Complete, the second message still finds that completed instance only... Is there a setting, which prevents more than 1 instance created?
public class SimpleSaga : SqlSaga<SimpleSagaData>,
    IAmStartedByMessages<StartProcessingSimpleSagaCommand>,
    IHandleMessages<EndSimpleSagaCommand>
{

    protected override string CorrelationPropertyName => nameof(SimpleSagaData.ProcessId);

    protected override void ConfigureMapping(IMessagePropertyMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.ConfigureMapping<StartProcessingSimpleSagaCommand>(c => c.ProcessId);
        mapper.ConfigureMapping<EndSimpleSagaCommand>(c => c.ProcessId);
    }

    public async Task Handle(StartProcessingSimpleSagaCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Data.ProcessId))
        {
            Data.ProcessId = message.ProcessId;
        }
        else if (Data.ProcessId != message.ProcessId)
        {
            throw new Exception("Only one Saga per ProcessId is allowed!");
        }

        //Sends another message with ProcessId, which will send back EndSimpleSagaCommand with the same ProcessId
    }

    public async Task Handle(EndSimpleSagaCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (Data.ProcessId != message.ProcessId)
        {
            throw new Exception("Saga does not match!");
        }

        MarkAsComplete();
    }
}

Configuration:
        var persistence = endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<SqlPersistence>();

        var dialect = persistence.SqlDialect<SqlDialect.MsSqlServer>();
        dialect.Schema("nsb");
        persistence.ConnectionBuilder(connectionBuilder: () => new SqlConnection(ConnectionString));

        persistence.TablePrefix("");

        var subscriptions = persistence.SubscriptionSettings();
        subscriptions.CacheFor(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        endpointConfiguration.EnableFeature<TimeoutManager>();
        endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo($"{OwnEndpointName}.errors");
        endpointConfiguration.AssemblyScanner().ExcludeAssemblies("tools");

        endpointConfiguration.LimitMessageProcessingConcurrencyTo(1);

        ConfigureUnobtrusiveMessageConvention(endpointConfiguration);

        endpointConfiguration.Recoverability().Delayed(DelayedSettings);

Simple test which is failing to prove that I am sending two different ProcessId's:
    [Test]
    public async Task Test()
    {

        var startCommand = new StartProcessingSimpleSagaCommand
        {
            ProcessId = "OneReg1"
        };

        var startCommand2 = new StartProcessingSimpleSagaCommand
        {
            ProcessId = "OneReg2"
        };

        await _simpleSaga.Handle(startCommand, _messageContext)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _simpleSaga.Handle(startCommand2, _messageContext)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

I will always get one of exceptions... Anyone can help?

Are you sending both starting messages with the same ProcessId? Because that's how a saga instance would be correlated to those messages.

@Sean Feldman Oh course no, then there would be no point of this post :) But thanks for interest!

@SeanFeldman that's why I introduced that "new Exception", which is thrown because different ProcessId came in.

I don't see anything wrong with the mapping. Try cross-posting at https://discuss.particular.net/

Your test is broken because it's picking the instance to send messages to and it's simply reusing one instance. You need to be using more of the actual NServiceBus infrastructure if you want it to be performing Saga handling properly here.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for pointing out! I actually used TestableMessageHandlerContext to test it... How then I can use actual infrastructure through UnitTests or IntegrationTests, but actually not insert rows in persistence table?

Saga Scenario Testing

@Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you! This proved that my Saga is creating instances correctly!
But I still have two problems to deal with:

If I want to use this UnitTest I need to change my Saga to regular Saga not SqlSaga. Because TestableSaga doesn't recognize SqlSaga. Do you know why?
How to use TestableSaga in larger Integration Test, where my saga is started in one of other Handlers?


@mr_city SqlSaga and TestableSaga aren't compatible because they don't both inherit Saga. SqlSaga inherits Saga (as show here: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql/blob/master/src/SqlPersistence/Saga/SqlSaga.cs), but TestableSaga, doesn't: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Testing/blob/master/src/NServiceBus.Testing/Sagas/TestableSaga.cs

Regarding your second question, I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve. The IAmStartedBy interface ensures that any messages using that marker interface can start the saga, but only one message will ever start the saga; that design is intentional. More information about this can be found here: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/
What use case are you trying to test exactly?
